# How to loop through elements that have no real connection?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I know there's a way to loop through these, but I'm too stupid to understand how. I mean in efficient way

```
def check_arr(arr, divisor, d_count):
    if (len(arr) == 3):
        if (arr[0] + arr[1] % divisor == 0):
            d_count += 1
        if (arr[0] + arr[2] % divisor == 0):
            d_count += 1
        if (arr[1] + arr[2] % divisor == 0):
            d_count += 1
        return d_count
```

Comment: May you spare a few words to explain what it is you're trying to do…?

Comment: It's a recursive function that searches for every sum of every element of the array and this is the last check. "arr[0]" is a sum of every number in previous recursive events

Answer (score 1):

You can use two nested loops to achieve the desired result.

```py
def check_arr(arr, divisor, d_count):
    if (len(arr) == 3):   # Not sure if you should really check this
      for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
          if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) % divisor == 0):
            d_count += 1

      return d_count
```